# Consistently inconsistent/blobby first layer

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, pla, extrusion, bowden

**Info:**

Printer - Creality Ender 3 V2 (slightly modified)

- replaced original hotend with another standard hotend (same model)
- PEI coated magnetic bed (printing on rough side.)
- CRTouch ABL

Filament - Sunlu Marble PLA+ (~1.5 weeks old) / JAYO White PLA+ (opened today)

Slicer - PrusaSlicer 2.6.0

Firmware - E3V2S1/"Professional Firmware" build 20230312

Settings -

- 0.4 mm nozzle (and set to 0.4 mm in slicer)
- 0.12 mm layer height (same for first)
- 210 °C nozzle, 55 °C bed
- extrusion multiplier of 1 (100 %)
- relatively slow print speed (40 mm/s or less)

**The Issue:**

Started printing marble PLA+ without problems for approx. a week, then had issues with the first layer. A mix of inconsistent- and under-extrusion. I figured the nozzle was clogged since marble filament is more prone to clogging and ended up swapping to another 0.4 mm nozzle.

Printed one model flawlessly, then the same issue again. Inconsistent extrusion leading to a rough and weak first layer. Swapped the nozzle again and decided to print in standard PLA+ to see if the filament was the issue. It wasn't - got another decent first print (temp tower), then I observed the same issue with both rolls of filament I mentioned, so I doubt it's bad tolerances there.

**Other things I've tried (to no avail):**

- calibrated E-Steps (they were already 98 % to perfect)
- checked nozzle clogs (extruding manually works perfectly fine, doubt it's clogged)
- checked extruder arm for cracks (no cracks)
- checked extruder tension (doesn't skip)
- re-leveled bed (and generated mesh) for every print
- adjusted flow during printing (120 % still had inconsistencies)
- swapped nozzles (4 times in total now) to see if I just got a bad one
- checked if my x-gantry wasn't level

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what else could cause this.
Here's some images, apologies if they're too fuzzy, it's the best my camera would do.

[image: A close-up of the lines]

[image: Inconsistent lines showing up only on the back and right side]

[image: Poor first layer as a result]